# Variavel com valor nulo ao chamar o método do model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou trabalhando com `codeigniter`. Ao submeter um formulário estou enviando os dados ao `model` através de getters e setters.

Este é meu `input`

```
div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_label('Fornecedores (CNPJ - Razão Social):*', 'fornecedor'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_dropdown('fornecedor', $fornecedores, set_value('fornecedor'), array("class" => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required'))?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Ao clicar em submit, entra em um método no controller tem este código:

```
 $this->load->model('Movimento_model', 'movimento');
 $this->movimento->setCnpj($this->input->post('fornecedor'));

 echo $this->movimento->getCnpj(); // exibe para teste
```

Este é meu model (resumido):

```
class Movimento_model extends CI_Model {

 private $cnpj;

 public function setCnpj($cnpj)
{
    $this->cnpj = strtoupper(trim($cnpj));
}

 public function getCnpj()
{
    return $this->$cnpj; // LINHA DO ERRO
}
```

Este é o erro:

> Undefined variable: cnpj

Obs: Estou setando mas parece que não está aceitando.
Quando tento exibir que ocorre o erro.

Answer (score -1):

Cara tenta seta um valor inicial para a variável

```
class Movimento_model extends CI_Model {

private $cnpj;
$this->cnpj = 0;

public function setCnpj($cnpj)
{
    $this->cnpj = strtoupper(trim($cnpj));
}

public function getCnpj()
{
    return $this->$cnpj; // LINHA DO ERRO
}
```